# How to import data from file and print in ordered columns in Java

Tags: java

My teacher gave an assignment that I am not fully understanding. It is in java. Here is the assignment:

Sales Report

You are to write a program that will get the information from a file. The file name is Inventory.dat.
  The format of the records of this file in order are:
   item number (integer)
   item name (string)
   number sold (integer)
   cost (double)

there may be multiple records for each item name. there is no sequence to this file.

you are to produce a report that shows the item name, quantity sold(number sold) and cost for that item. the report sequence will be in descending order.

there will be a total at the bottom of the page. 
you need to print the report in three columns with column headings.

That is the assignment, and here is my code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        FileReader freader = new FileReader("E:/Personal/Inventory.dat");
        BufferedReader file = new BufferedReader(freader);
        int numberSold;
        double cost;
        String numberSoldParse;
        String costParse;
        double costTotal = 0;
        int numberSoldTotal = 0;
//        
        //print column headings
        System.out.println("Item Name:        Qty Sold:       Total:");

        for (String itemName = file.readLine(); itemName != null; itemName = file.readLine()) {
            //print file in columns
            numberSoldParse = file.readLine();
            numberSold = Integer.parseInt(numberSoldParse);
            costParse = file.readLine();
            cost = Double.parseDouble(costParse);
            //totals
            costTotal = costTotal + cost;
            numberSoldTotal = numberSoldTotal + numberSold;
            //sort

            System.out.printf("%-21s %-10s %4.2f%n", itemName, numberSold, cost);
        }

        //print totals
        System.out.println("___________________________________________");
        System.out.printf("%-21s %-10d %4.2f%n", "Total:", numberSoldTotal, costTotal);
        System.exit(0);
    }

}
```

Here is my output. How can i get them in descending order by cost column? I am stumped. Please help.

```
Item Name:        Qty Sold:       Total:
Malibu                1          20000.00
Subaru                2          20000.00
F150                  1          30000.00
Camaro                1          30000.00
BMW                   1          30000.00
Audi                  2          29000.00
___________________________________________
Total:                8          159000.00
```

Comment: You will need to accumulate the data in some fashion. Add each item (a line) to a Collection of some sort (I would probably create an object such as SoldItem to represent each line, but no school assignment seems to care at all about OO that I've seen). Then loop over the Collection, gathering the totals, sort and output.

Comment: I am not allowed to use ArrayList. only normal arrays and bubblesort

Comment: Anything you can do with an ArrayList can be handled in a non-OO fashion with arrays. But if you have constraints, you need to list those in your question, as they are part of the requirements. You should also read what **is** in the assignment, which states there can be more than one line for a given item, and no where in the original code are you accumulating by item.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the portion where you are reading in the data (and printing to the console) [given that you can use `only normal arrays and bubblesort`]

You can have 3 arrays. I don't know how many max entries you have, but say you have 100.

```
String[] itemNames = new String[100];
int[] numbersSold = new int[100];
double[] costs = new double[100];
int curIndx = 0;

for (String itemName = file.readLine(); itemName != null; itemName = file.readLine()) {
    // add item name
    itemNames[curIndx] = itemName;

    //print file in columns
    numberSoldParse = file.readLine();
    numberSold = Integer.parseInt(numberSoldParse);

    // add number sold
    numbersSold[curIndx] = numberSold;

    costParse = file.readLine();
    cost = Double.parseDouble(costParse);

    // add cost
    costs[curIndx] = cost;

    // increment indx pointer 
    curIndx++;
}
```

For the bubble-sort on descending order of cost. While swapping, ensure that appropriate indices of the `itemNames` and `numbersSold` are swapped alongside the indices of `costs`.

Once that is done, you can go on with your printing as normal. Let me know if something is not clear. I'll add more code or whatever is required. :)

Answer (score 0):

Since you are learning Java, why don't you write codes in Object Oriented way?

You can setup a class called item to collect your data with name/cost,and another class called sale to collect different item's total, then you can sort them with comparators.

Answer (score 0):

There could be more than 1 way to achieve your desired solution. One way I would do it is using a Map of String object as the key and a List object of Maps of String, Integer as the value. E.g. `Map<String, ArrayList<Map<String, Integer>>> hashMap = new HashMap<String, ArrayList>();` So in your 'for' loop, instead of printing the data on console for each line, I will add the data to this map. So in this case, the "total" will be the key to the main map. And a list of maps (inner map) of item as the key and quantity as the value  will be the value for the main map. While adding each entry to the outer map, you will have to check if the map already contains that key (total). If it does, you will have to first retrieve its value (which is a list of total and qty map) and then add the new entry to the list and re-add the updated list back to the outer map. Finally, once the outer map is fully populated, you can do a Collections sort method on the key (total). Then run another for loop to print those sorted entries in the format you desire.

I know that I am proposing a complicated approach to achieve your objective. But if you don't find any solution, you can try this approach. Let me know if I can be of further help.

Comment: It would be easier to do `Map<String, double[]>`, look up if it exists (create a `new double[2]` if not and add under the name). Increase the totals in the found double array as appropriate. Less complexity.

Comment: @KevinO, what will be the key in this map? "item name"? If yes, how about the "quantity of items"? Also, how will the sorting be done? Can you explain a little?

Comment: Yes, the item name would be the key, quantity is double[0], and total is double[1]. I am assuming the point is to read a file that has duplicate entries, collect the total amount for a given entry (e.g., there are multiple Suburu sales, and the goal is to have an accumulation of all the sales; I am finding the instructions a bit unclear). If the point is merely to read every line and then sort, then the solution would be a bit different. Then, from the map, process the Map.Entry set.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution I can think of which is also a little complex is about defining a new class called "SalesData" that will implement the java.lang.Comparable interface. E.g. `public class SalesData implements Comparable<SalesData>`. There will be 3 member fields of this class: 1. Item name 2. quantity 3. total sale. You will add a compareTo method to this class which can do the comparison of the 2 SalesData object only on the basis of the "total sale" field. In your for loop, rather than printing the data, you would create an object of SalesData class with this data. At the end of reading all the lines, you will have a list of "SalesData" objects. Then you can call Collections.sort on this list. The sort will use your compareTo method in the class SalesData to do the sorting. Once sorted, you can print the data in the desired format. Let me know if I can provide more info.

Comment: Also, OP has said in comments, `I am not allowed to use ArrayList. only normal arrays and bubblesort`

Comment: It was not an addendum. It was a separate answer. Also nowhere in the problem description has the OP mentioned that he was not allowed to use an ArrayList. Even if he is not allowed to use ArrayList, he can use alternate  List objects like CopyOnWriteArrayList. My intention was to give a conceptual solution.